# one-to-many problems

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, one-to-many

hello
I execute query by hbm mapping. Query contains one-to-many property .I want save it in the bag.
Number of results is 100. But I have 100 times the first result. 
Where is my error??

Comment: Please post the hbm file and query

Comment: `**<class name="Entity" table="A"><id ....column="id"> <bag name="child"> <key column="ID"/><one-to-many class="Child"/></bag> <class name="Child"> <id.......column="ID"> <dinamic-component name="Details">...... </dinamic-component>**`

Answer (score 0):

Use distinct when you use the query.

Comment: I don't build the query . I use createCriteria of Nhibernate and UniqueResult()

Comment: Did you try setting the transformer criteria.setResultTransformer() to  distinctrootelement?

Comment: createCriteria(<ABC>.class).setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();
This is in Hibernate, should there be an equivalent in nHibernate

Comment: In NHibernate it's CriteriaUtil.DistinctRootEntity . 
But it didn't help . 
Why I get 100 times same line??

Comment: Maybe you didn't define the relationship well, and you get a cartesian join